# Preserve spaces in column headers using sqlsave in r

Tags: sql-server, r

How can I save spaces in column headers when writing data to Microsoft SQL Server from R?

Note, I want spaces in the column names because this is a correlation table with keywords/phrases against keyword/phrases.  I can put IDs as column names, but eventually the end user will want to see column names as the phrase actually is.  There is a difference between "go skateboard" and "goskateboard".

Here's some code to clarify the issue.

```
# Load RODBC package
library(RODBC)

# Connect to database (write database name in quoted area)
con <- odbcConnect("")

# Generate random matrix
mat_test <- matrix(rnorm(12), 4, 3)

# Label column headers
colnames(mat_test) <- c("A","A B", "C")

# Change matrix to dataframe
df_test <- as.data.frame(mat_test)

# View data frame.  Note how there is a space in the column header labled "A B"
View(df_test)

# Write data frame to database.  Why is the space gone?  How do I preserve the space?
sqlSave(con, df_test, tablename = "12_Test_12", rownames = FALSE, colnames = TRUE)
```

Comment: Names with spaces are not syntactically valid column names within R. You can have them, but you shouldn't. This exact reason why there is a `check.names` parameter in `read.table` (which is set to default `= TRUE`) and there is a special function called `make.names`. In short, my advice to you - don't create such names and get over with it.

Comment: Provided that the columns in your data frame and in your SQL table are in the same order, would it be possible to save to the table regardless of column names?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the column name to "[A B]". SQL server doesn't like spaces in column names sometimes unless they are wrapped in brackets.
EDIT: I should perhaps also mention that most people recommend against using spaces in column names, as it can easily get confusing and often requires more work, and a common solution would be to use an underscore instead: "A_B".

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I agree, typically I prefer not having spaces in column names.  The issue here is that each column references a keyword or keyword phrase.  I could label the columns from IDs; however, I want the table to be more easily interpretable.

Comment: I can't comment on David's R specific info. But it might help to know that the brackets have special use in SQL Server for specifying names - if you were to create a column in sql server called "[A B]" it would display as "A B" to a user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   I used make names, but I have the same issue when writing the column names to the SQL Server database.  Using make.names "A B" becomes "A.B".  However, when I write the column to the database, I get "AB".  This is the same issue as before. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: # Create a row with the make.names function
df_test2 <- rbind(Keywords = make.names(colnames(df_test)), df_test)

# Change column names to use the make.names row
colnames(df_test2) <- df_test2[1,]

# Remove first row
df_test2 <- df_test2[-1,]

# View table
View(df_test2)
Here is an example using make.names
# Write data frame to database.  The period that was placed between A and B "A.B" is removed and is simply "AB"
sqlSave(con, df_test2, tablename = "01_Test_02", rownames = FALSE, colnames = TRUE)